# How to determine whether data has been retrieved from disk or from caches?

Tags: c++, c

I have written a program in C/C++ which needs to fetch data from the disk. After some time it so happens that the operating system stores some of the data in its caches. Is there some way by which I may figure out in a C/c++ programs whether the data has been retrieved from the caches or the data has been retrieved from the disk?

Comment: That looks like something that will be hard to do. Can you tell us why you need to make that distinction ?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to do this. The OS goes to great pains to make sure that you don't have to care.

Comment: @ChrisHayes actually, you often do want to know this when optimizing software, you want to know if you are getting more cache hits than hard reads

Comment: @KeithNicholas Yes you are correct?

Comment: On windows, there are various performance counters that can help with this task, of course this is platform-specific.

Comment: @KeithNicholas When writing the application, yes. You probably wouldn't want to base your actual runtime operations on it though.

Comment: @Chris O I am on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @ChrisHayes Actually i need to figure out why my application is performing worse than postgresql. I have confirmed that postgresql is indeed fetching data from the cache..instead of fetching it from the disk

Comment: @ChrisHayes Like Keith Nicolas mentioned, to spot and solve performances problems, I often struggle to get the worst of my hardware in order to have reproductible test cases.

Comment: There are many tools which exist to analyze the caching behavior of your application, such as cachegrind. You don't need (or want) to embed something into your own application code to figure it out.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Can you please help me as to how can I use cachegrind with interactive programs

Comment: Note that `cachegrind` is for CPU caches (the L1, L2 and L3 data caches built into your CPU), and not disk caches.  For disk cache behavior (at least on Linux), check out this article: http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/io-profiling

Comment: There are at least two relevant caches: OS-managed in main memory and disk-managed (on controller). There's rarely a disk without a few MB of RAM today, but its hit% won't be reflected in the OS figures.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to time the read operation. Disk reads are significantly slower. you can read a a group of file blocks (4K) twice to get an estimate.
The problem is that if you run the program again or copy the file in a shell, the OS will cache it.